# CSS - control the ellipsis slide animation

Tags: css

I'm trying to control the animation when user hovers and moves away from the text.

I tried to use both animation + transition, but so far didn't work

e.g for the style i used

```
animation-timing-function: ease;
animation-duration: 1000s;
transform-origin: top;

transition: all 1000s ease-in-out;
```

```css
p:not(:hover) {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

p:hover {
  transition: all 100000000s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<p>
  As for when that happeneAnd she is also going to cut back a little on the kind of art that she does. She used to do high - resolution pieces, but now she's mostly doing "modifications," mostly paintings of dogs. She's getting older, she says, and it takes
  a lot out of her, so she wants to keep that stuff to a minimum.
</p>
```

please pure css only

Comment: You can only animate numeric values in CSS.

Comment: @HaoWu can you explain a little more on that please? is there any different between alphabet characters and numeric values in animation?

Comment: For numeric values, let's say `0px` and `100px`, the in-between state of them is `50px` which is reasonable. But there's no in-between state between two different states. Like there's no such thing as half of a banana and half of an apple. For `text-overflow: ellipsis`, the browser don't know how to animate it from `ellipsis` to `clip` smoothly. So it just jump from one state to another, despite of the duration.

Comment: i see, is there a work around so i can use animation or translation to show hidden text?